# How can I fix this Segmentation fault using SFML?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I am having a segmentation fault error when running this code
The error is triggered at the draw function of the custom object.
I believe that its related to the address of the window.

```
GameObject *obj = new Dummy;

//game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    window.clear();
    obj->draw(window);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
```

}

I pasted the whole code [here](http://pastebin.com/GxDW4a8L)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.
The problem was that I was loosing the texture cause it wasn't created with new, so after the constructor created it then the sprite was banished.