# Drawing sprite causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm writing a simple game in SFML2, which is based on isometric tiles. Each tile in the map is represented by Tile class. The class contains sf::Sprite object and `draw()` function which is supposed to draw the sprite on the screen. The problem is that invoking `window.draw()` causes Segmentation Fault. I've read that it's usually caused by associated sf::Texture pointer not being valid, but I've checked that and it's not the case.

(Texture reference is passed to the Tile constructor using `ResourceManager<sf::Texture>` object)

tile.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "resource_manager.hpp"

class Tile
{
public:
  Tile(const sf::Texture& texture);

  void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, const float dt);

private:
  sf::Sprite _sprite;
};
```

tile.cpp:

```
#include "tile.hpp"

Tile::Tile(const sf::Texture& texture)
{
  _sprite.setTexture(texture);
}

void Tile::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, const float dt)
{
  std::cout << _sprite.getTexture()->getSize().x << std::endl; //Texture pointer works fine
  window.draw(_sprite); //Segmentation Fault here
}
```

map.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "resource_holder.hpp"
#include "tile.hpp"

class Map
{
public:
  Map(ResourceHolder& resources, int width, int height);

  void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, const float dt);

private:
  ResourceHolder& _resources;
  int _width, _height;

  std::vector<Tile> _tiles;
};
```

map.cpp:

```
#include "map.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Map::Map(ResourceHolder& resources, int width, int height)
  : _resources(resources), _width(width), _height(height)
{
  _tiles.reserve(width * height);

  for(int y = 0; y < _height; ++y)
  {
    for(int x = 0; x < _width; ++x)
    {
      _tiles[x + y * _width] = Tile(_resources.textures["groundTile_NE"]);
    }
  }
}

void Map::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, const float dt)
{
  for(int x = 0; x < _width; ++x)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < _height; ++y)
    {
      _tiles[x + y * _width].draw(window, dt);
    }
 }
}
```

resource_manager.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Resource>
class ResourceManager
{
public:
  ResourceManager(const std::string& directory, const std::string& extension)
    : _directory("assets/" + directory + "/"), _extension("." + extension)
  {}

  Resource& operator[](const std::string& name)
  {
    return get(name);
  }

  Resource& get(const std::string& name)
  {
    if(!exists(name))
      load(name);

    return _resources.at(name);
  }

  bool exists(const std::string& name) const
  {
    return _resources.find(name) != _resources.end();
  }

  void load(const std::string& name)
  {
    Resource res;
    if(!res.loadFromFile(_directory + name + _extension))
    {
      res.loadFromFile(_directory + "_fail_" + _extension);
    }

    _resources.insert({name, res});
  }

private:
  const sf::String _directory;
  const sf::String _extension;

  std::unordered_map<std::string, Resource> _resources;
};
```

Comment: @Eddge It does return pointer, my mistake

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Resource is a template typename. It's sf::Texture in this case

Comment: oops forgive me, I didn't see the template declaration. Comment deleted

Comment: Thanks for fixing that @Hadenir can you show us how you are loading the texture and how you are verifying that it loaded correctly?

Comment: I've edited the question and added map.cpp and map.hpp where the loading is performed. `_sprite.getTexture()->getSize().x` returns correct width so i assume texture is loaded correctly

Comment: @Hadenir in your load method for the ResourceManager, can you verify that it is indeed loading correctly?  you call `if(!res.loadFromFile(_directory + name + _extension))`  but if that fails to load you call `res.loadFromFile(_directory + "_fail_" + _extension);`  which doesn't necessarily mean the second file loaded correctly.  can you verify that atleast one of those is true?  for example just print out if the second 1 fails.  other then that there isn't really enough here to thoroughly investigate what else could be causing the problem.

Comment: @Eddge But `_sprite.getTexture()->getSize()` returns correct size. Doesn't it mean the texture is loaded correctly?

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want your Map and Tile classes to inherit from sf::Drawable and override it's draw function.

Comment: Not Necessarily, I dont know whats under the hood of `loadFromFile()`  so I wouldn't use that as grounds to verify it loaded correctly.  another possibility is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008187/how-can-i-fix-this-segmentation-fault-using-sfml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the SFML source code ([Graphics/Texture.cpp](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp)), the destructor causes the OpenGL texture buffer to be deleted:

```
Texture::~Texture()
{
    // Destroy the OpenGL texture
    if (m_texture)
    {
        TransientContextLock lock;

        GLuint texture = static_cast<GLuint>(m_texture);
        glCheck(glDeleteTextures(1, &texture));
    }
}
```

In your `load` method, you allocate the object `res` on the stack. This means that when the method returns, the destructor of `Resource` will be called on the `res` object. Your OpenGL handle is deleted, but still stored in the *copy* of `res` which you insert into `_resources`.

To work around this, store *pointers* of the resource classes instead:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Resource*> _resources;

...

void load(const std::string& name)
{
   Resource* res = new Resource();
   if (!res->loadFromFile(_directory + name + _extension))
   {
      res->loadFromFile(_directory + "_fail_" + _extension);
   }

   _resources.insert({name, res});
}

Resource* operator[](const std::string& name)
{
   return get(name);
}

Resource* get(const std::string& name)
{
   if (!exists(name))
      load(name); // or return nullptr

   return _resources.at(name);
}
```

But you also need to destroy these pointers when the `ResourceManager` object is destroyed:

```
~ResourceManager()
{
   for (auto& pair : _resources)
      delete pair.second;
}
```

Note: you may be tempted to store *references* in `_resources`. But see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543193/why-cant-i-store-references-in-an-stl-map-in-c) for why that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: It explains a lot, thanks. I based my manager on this code: https://github.com/Hopson97/SFML-Game-Framework/blob/master/Source/ResourceManager/ResourceManager.h I wonder why it worked for him, but not in my case.

Comment: @Hadenir hmm, not to be overly skeptical about a well-known blogger, but are you sure that it **works** for him? I mean, your code (and thus his) *compiles* fine, but I can't find where he actually *uses* `ResourceManager/Holder` anywhere in the repository. Maybe we ought to ask the man himself?

Comment: I was thinking the same, but on video he did the textures worked fine. Nevertheless thanks for the help meowgoesthedog!